# Refresh asset publisher portlet liferay6.2

Tags: javascript, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I need to refresh asset publisher portlet every 5 minutes..

Liferay 6.2 ce ga2

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the **solution** I followed :

- Step 1 : Go to "Admin" > "site administration" > "Private pages"
- Step 2 : Insert the following script in Javascript" in the right side:

  ```
  function refreshPortlet(){
        Liferay.Portlet.refresh('.portlet-asset-publisher');
        setInterval(refreshPortlet, 300000); 
  }
  refreshPortlet();
  ```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Using `setInterval` javascript method and `Liferay.Portlet.refresh("#p_p_id<portlet:namespace/>")`, you can achieve that.

For Example:

```
function refreshPortlet(){
Liferay.Portlet.refresh("#p_p_id_19_");
setInterval(refreshPortlet, 10000); 
}
refreshPortlet();
```

Above code will refresh Message board portlet every 10 seconds.

In case of asset publisher, portlet namespace would be something like `101_INSTANCE_bsWWbeve8ffA_`

You can place your code in jsp of asset-publisher-portlet by overriding it with hook.